# List of Tuples to Pivoted Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Processed data from multipe sources and created a list of tuples. I converted this list into a dataframe. Using the following command

```
df = pd.DataFrame(FinalPivotTable)        
    df.pivot(index=0,columns=1,values=2)
```

I am trying to create a pivot table (Input and Output Example below):

- Column 0 (Currently) would be Unique ROWS
- Column 1 (Currently) Would be Unique COLUMNS
- Column 2 (Currently) Would be the VALUES that intersect Column 0 and Column 1

print(df)

```
                                              0                      1   2
0                                       RMG BOW  Business Case Summary   8
1                              Model Onboarding  Business Case Summary  15
2           Equity Derivatives Model Onboarding  Business Case Summary   4
3                                       FXO BOW  Business Case Summary   3
4    Interest Rate Derivatives Model Onboarding  Business Case Summary   3
5                 Interest Rate Derivatives BOW  Business Case Summary  12
6        Interest Rate Options Model Onboarding  Business Case Summary   4
..                                          ...                    ...  ..
15               IT Sponsored Technical Roadmap  Business Case Summary   1
16                                  FXO Project  Business Case Summary   1
17                                  Finance BOW  Business Case Summary   1
18                                      RMG BOW           Linked Issue   8
19                             Model Onboarding           Linked Issue  15
20          Equity Derivatives Model Onboarding           Linked Issue   4
21                                      FXO BOW           Linked Issue   3
..                                          ...                    ...  ..
28                 Commodities Model Onboarding           Linked Issue   6
29                         RMG Model Onboarding           Linked Issue   1
..                                          ...                    ...  ..
71                                 Treasury BOW       XT2 Dev Required  14
72                Interest Rate Derivatives BOW       XT2 Dev Required   3
73          Equity Derivatives Model Onboarding       XT2 Dev Required   1
..                                          ...                    ...  ..
77                             Treasury Project       XT2 Dev Required   3
78               IT Sponsored Technical Roadmap       XT2 Dev Required   1
79                                  FXO Project       XT2 Dev Required   1
80                             Model Onboarding       XT2 Dev Required   1
81                                      RMG BOW          Curent Status   7
82                             Model Onboarding          Curent Status  15
83          Equity Derivatives Model Onboarding          Curent Status   3
84                                      FXO BOW          Curent Status   3
..                                          ...                    ...  ..
96                                  FXO Project          Curent Status   1
97                                  Finance BOW          Curent Status   1
98                                 Treasury BOW  Prioritization Status   1
99                             Treasury Project  Prioritization Status   3
100               Interest Rate Derivatives BOW    Prioritization Rank   2

[101 rows x 3 columns]
```

So result would look something like this:

```
            Business Case Summary   Linked Issue    XT2 Dev Required    Current Status  Prioritization Status

RMG BOW             8                   0                   0               7                   0
Model Onboarding    15                  15                  1               15                  0
```

Please and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) is what you need, if necessary replace `NaN` to `0`:

```
df.pivot(index=0,columns=1,values=2).fillna(0)
```

Only if get error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggreagate function like `first`, `mean`, `sum` ...:

```
#if columns are numbers
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=0, columns=1, values=2, aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)

print (df1)
```

Alternative solution is use `groupby`, agggreagte function like `mean` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby([0,1])[2].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!